# How to replace a specific .html into a trailing slash using HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this command in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

And this command remove the .html at the end this looks ok but how can I add at the end? Because if I try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

The .html is there again. I want to replace the .html into a trailing slash. And also I want to do this in 1 HTML file only. So my URL is like this for now.

```
http://mysamplesite.com/project.html/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+project\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/ [NC,L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try that :)

Comment: But when I try to navigate to other page the `projects/` is always there

Comment: The page for the `projects/` is fine but when I try to navigate to other page the `projects/` is appended

Comment: Oh ok. That is due to your use of relative link in `href`. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` .

Comment: Should I add the `base href` in all of my pages?

Comment: But what if I want to this also on my other pages? Should I copy this part `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+project\.html\s [NC]` and replace only the name of my html?

Comment: You can use: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:project|page2|page3)\.html\s [NC]` condition so that trailing slash is added to these 3 pages

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule I am assuming project is the file on which you want to apply trailing slash.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^project$ project/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```